# web sms configuration - receiving unwanted information

Tags: php, html, sms-gateway

I am using the code below for sending web mail and sms notifications. I would like to only receive clients' names and their enquiries in the SMS but as the enquiry field is not mandatory when the user leaves it blank I receive the header information. I tried to remove `$header` from the `mail(..,..,$header)` but then I won't receive any sms.

Here is PHP code:

```
if ($_POST['submit']) {
$to="myemailaddress@domain.com";
$sms="mymobilenumber@smsserviceprovider.com";
$subject="";
$from = "web@mywebsite.com";
$enquiry = $_REQUEST['enquiry'] ;
$headers = "From: $from\r\n" .
"MIME-Version: 1.0\r\n" .
"Content-Type: multipart/mixed;\r\n" .
" boundary=\"{$mime_boundary}\"";
$message="$name $enquiry";
@mail($sms, $message, $headers); }
```

The HTML code:

```
<form action="/thankyou.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" onsubmit="return validateForm();" >
<input type="text" name="name" />
<textarea name="enquiry"></textarea>
<input type="submit" value="submit" onclick="javascript:return validateMyForm();" />
</form>
```

This is what I get when the enquiry field is left unanswered:

> Sbj: Name Enquiry From: web@mywebsite.com MIME-Versian:1.0 Content-Type:....

This is What I want to receive:

> Name Enquiry

Appreciate your help

Solved: Ok here is what I did to solve the issue:
set up the new header for SMS as below:

```
$header = "From: $from\r\n" .
"Content-Type:text/plain;\r\n";

@mail($sms, $subject, $message, $header);
@mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
```

Comment: Why do you send message with `Content-Type` set to `multipart/mixed` and not `text/plain`? What you get seems like your sms service provider is ignoring the content type and treating the message as plain text...

Comment: I am sending attachments with the form to my Email. Should I set different header only for SMS?

Comment: It depends on your SMS provider, but it looks like you should send completely separate emails, one plain text to send sms, without attachments etc, and another to your email address, with attachments and whatever you want.